# HTTP Error 406: Not Acceptable Python urllib2

Tags: python, python-2.7, urllib2

I get the following error with the code below.

> HTTP Error 406: Not Acceptable Python urllib2

This is my first step before I use beautifulsoup to parse the page.

```
import urllib2
opener = urllib2.build_opener()
opener.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0')]
url = "http://www.choicemoney.us/retail.php"
response = opener.open(url)
```

All help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why you tagged both `python-2.7` and `python-3.x` , which you use?

Comment: I suppose he used `python2.x` since `urllib2` does not exist as a package in python3.

Answer (score 9):

> The resource identified by the request is only capable of generating
>      response entities which have content characteristics not acceptable
>      according to the accept headers sent in the request. [[RFC2616]](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.4.7)

Based on the code and what the RFC describes I assume that you need to set both the key and the value of the `User-Agent` header correctly.

These are correct examples:

- `Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686) Gecko/20071127 Firefox/2.0.0.11`
- `Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36`
- `Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_3) AppleWebKit/537.75.14 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/7.0.3 Safari/7046A194A`

Just replace the following.

```
opener.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_3) AppleWebKit/537.75.14 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/7.0.3 Safari/7046A194A')]
```

Comment: Should we make this a default User-agent header so that it works for all pages?

Comment: Yes, not a bad idea after all.

Answer (score 1):

I believe @ipinak's answer is correct.

`urllib2` actually provides a default User-Agent that works here, so if you delete `opener.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0')]` the response should have status code 200.

I recommend the popular [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) library for such jobs as its API is much easier to use.

```
url = "http://www.choicemoney.us/retail.php"
resp = requests.get(url)
print resp.status_code # 200
print resp.content # can be used in your beautifulsoup.
```

Comment: I believe the issue is the `User-Agent` not the `Content-Type`. If you provide a correct user agent then it works, without providing the content type.

Comment: I recommend requests as well, I have written a similar web scrapper for another site and I use requests. It is much cleaner.